# How to display custom taxonomy parent and child including the posts

Tags: wordpress, categories, custom-post-type, taxonomy, children

I'm currently working on a Wordpress-project which has to display all the categories, subcategories and posts within these subcategories of a custom post type & taxonomy.
I should become something like this:

- Category 1
- - subcategory
- - - post 1
- - - post 2
- - subcategory
- - - post 3
- Category 2
- - subcategory
- - - post 4

At this moment the code returns a list of all the categories and subcategories 
in the taxonomy between the h3-tags. Only the parent categories should be displayed here.

```
    <?php
    $terms = get_terms('resource_category', array('hierarchical' => false));
    foreach ($terms as $term) {

     $cat_slug = $term->slug;
     $cat_id = $term->term_id;
     $subcats = get_categories('child_of='.$cat_id.'&taxonomy=resource_category');
     if ( have_posts() ) :

     /* CATEGORY */ ?>
     <div class="resources">
     <?php echo '<h3>'.$term->name.'</h3>';

       /* SUBCATEGORY */
       foreach ($subcats as $subcat) {
       if ( have_posts() ) :
       echo '<h4>' . $subcat->name .'</h4>';
       query_posts('post_type=resources&resource_category='.$subcat->cat_name.'&hide_empty=1'); ?>
       <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

       /* SUBCATEGORY POSTS */?>
       <div class="resource-item">
       <ul>
         <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
       </ul>
       </div>
       <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();} ?>
       </div>

     <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); } ?>
```

Big thanks if anyone can help me with this!

Comment: To solve your first problem, change your arguments to `get_terms()` - you're telling it to not get heirarchical, but actually what you need to do is set it like so: `array('parent'=>0)`, which will cause it to only get top-level terms. [get_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)

Answer (score 1):

$terms = get_terms('mobile_category', array('hide_empty'=> 0,'orderby'=> 'count','parent' => 0));
foreach ($terms as $term) {

```
 $cat_slug = $term->slug;
 $cat_id = $term->term_id;
 $subcats = get_categories('child_of='.$cat_id.'&taxonomy=mobile_category');
```

//  if ( have_posts() ) :

```
 /* CATEGORY */ ?>
 <div class="resources">
 <?php echo '<h3>cat pr1 --  '.$term->name.'</h3>';

   /* SUBCATEGORY */
   foreach ($subcats as $subcat) {
   if ( have_posts() ) :
   echo '<h4>sub 2 ' . $subcat->name .'</h4>';
   query_posts('post_type=mobile&mobile_category='.$subcat->cat_name.'&hide_empty=1'); ?>
   <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();    

   /* SUBCATEGORY POSTS */?>
   <div class="resource-item">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
   </ul>
   </div>
   <?php endwhile;
```

endif;
wp_reset_query();}